# Displaying error bars around data series on dygraph in R

Tags: r, dygraphs

I would like to display error bars around data series on dygraph like the image in this link (http://www.webappers.com/2009/12/15/produce-interactive-charts-of-time-series-with-dygraphs/). I have used the following r code to draw the dygraph.

```
weather_final <- read.csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/weather_data.csv")
weather_final1<- as.data.frame(weather_final  , header=True)
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)

s <- xts(weather_final1[, 2:3 ], order.by=as.POSIXct(weather_final1$Datetime,"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M" ))

head(s)
dygraph(s)%>% 
  dyRoller(showRoller = TRUE,rollPeriod = 48)%>% 
  dyHighlight(highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha = 2,
              hideOnMouseOut = TRUE )%>%
  dyRangeSelector(height = 40, strokeColor = "RED")%>%
  dyAxis("y", label = "Temp (0C)", valueRange = c(10, 40) )%>%
  dyAxis("y2", valueRange = c(10, 100)) %>%
  dyAxis("y2", label = "RH (%)",independentTicks = TRUE) %>%
  dySeries("RH", axis = 'y2')
```

Here is the output dygraph [image: example of dygraph]

I appreciate any help to draw error bars on both series!

Here below sample data. Data collected every 30 minutes for six months.

```
Datetime    Temp    RH
2014-12-25 0:00 19.5    49.8
2014-12-25 0:30 19.6    49.1
2014-12-25 1:00 20.1    46.1
2014-12-25 1:30 20.8    43.8
2014-12-25 2:00 21.5    44.7
2014-12-25 2:30 22.8    41.1
2014-12-25 3:00 23.7    39.2
2014-12-25 3:30 24.9    36.2
2014-12-25 4:00 25.5    34.6
2014-12-25 4:30 25.6    33.5
2014-12-25 5:00 25.6    33.7
2014-12-25 5:30 26.1    32.9
2014-12-25 6:00 26.3    32
2014-12-25 6:30 26.4    31.9
2014-12-25 7:00 26.8    31.4
2014-12-25 7:30 26.7    31.3
2014-12-25 8:00 26.2    31.8
2014-12-25 8:30 25.9    31.7
2014-12-25 9:00 25.3    35.6
2014-12-25 9:30 24.4    42.6
2014-12-25 10:00 24.1   45.7
2014-12-25 10:30 23.8   45.8
2014-12-25 11:00 23.3   42.3
2014-12-25 11:30 22.8   45.1
2014-12-25 12:00 22.5   47.4
2014-12-25 12:30 22     50
2014-12-25 13:00 22.1   51
2014-12-25 13:30 21.3   51.4
2014-12-25 14:00 21.4   52.6
2014-12-25 14:30 21.4   52.2
2014-12-25 15:00 21.4   55
2014-12-25 15:30 21.2   54.6
2014-12-25 16:00 20.9   54.5
2014-12-25 16:30 20.2   50.3
2014-12-25 17:00 19.9   52.9
2014-12-25 17:30 20     56.3
2014-12-25 18:00 19.9   56.3
2014-12-25 18:30 19.8   57.2
2014-12-25 19:00 19.8   57.5
2014-12-25 19:30 19.7   57.5
2014-12-25 20:00 19.3   56.8
2014-12-25 20:30 19.2   57.8
2014-12-25 21:00 18.9   58
2014-12-25 21:30 18.7   58.2
2014-12-25 22:00 18.5   58.6
2014-12-25 22:30 18.4   56.3
2014-12-25 23:00 18.3   54.8
2014-12-25 23:30 18.3   50.2
2014-12-26 0:00 18.3    50.2
2014-12-26 0:30 18.4    47.9
2014-12-26 1:00 18.9    46.9
2014-12-26 1:30 19.8    46.5
2014-12-26 2:00 20.8    44.5
2014-12-26 2:30 22.3    38.9
2014-12-26 3:00 23.1    38.5
2014-12-26 3:30 24.1    36.2
2014-12-26 4:00 24.7    35.3
2014-12-26 4:30 25.4    34
2014-12-26 5:00 25.2    33.5
2014-12-26 5:30 25.7    31.3
2014-12-26 6:00 25.8    32.7
2014-12-26 6:30 26.1    32
2014-12-26 7:00 25.7    28.9
2014-12-26 7:30 25.7    27.6
2014-12-26 8:00 25.4    29.2
2014-12-26 8:30 25.2    29.8
2014-12-26 9:00 24.5    34.9
2014-12-26 9:30 23.6    39
2014-12-26 10:00 22.7   42.1
2014-12-26 10:30 22.2   43
2014-12-26 11:00 22     44.1
2014-12-26 11:30 22.1   46.7
2014-12-26 12:00 21.7   45.5
2014-12-26 12:30 21.2   48.1
2014-12-26 13:00 21.2   50.4
2014-12-26 13:30 20.8   49.6
2014-12-26 14:00 20.5   49.2
2014-12-26 14:30 20.1   45.1
2014-12-26 15:00 20.2   50.2
2014-12-26 15:30 20.1   52.8
2014-12-26 16:00 19.9   51.9
2014-12-26 16:30 19.7   50.7
2014-12-26 17:00 19.5   51.8
2014-12-26 17:30 19.5   54.3
2014-12-26 18:00 19.1   54.1
2014-12-26 18:30 18.6   55.9
2014-12-26 19:00 18.8   55.6
2014-12-26 19:30 18.6   56.3
2014-12-26 20:00 18.5   56.3
2014-12-26 20:30 18.3   56.4
2014-12-26 21:00 18.1   56.6
2014-12-26 21:30 17.8   55.8
2014-12-26 22:00 17.8   56.3
2014-12-26 22:30 17.6   56.4
2014-12-26 23:00 17.4   52.4
2014-12-26 23:30 17.4   51.2
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @Mohammadian, here sample data.

Comment: Plotting "error bars" requires stating a statistical model and you haven't said what that might be.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided a reproducible example, so here's a basic example, adapted from the [vignette](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-upper-lower-bars.html), using built-in data:

```
# Data and fake confidence intervals
set.seed(5)
dat = cbind(ldeaths, 
            lwr=ldeaths - rnorm(length(ldeaths), 500, 20), 
            upr=ldeaths + rnorm(length(ldeaths), 500, 20))

dygraph(dat) %>%
  dySeries(c("lwr","ldeaths","upr"))
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried it, but doesn't work. It is better to provide CSV data. How can I upload it?

Comment: sample data added to the post as it is impossible to upload CSV data.

Comment: Take the same sample data you posted and repost it using `dput`. Just paste in the output of `dput(data_sample)`.

Comment: Your data doesn't include values for the confidence intervals. How do you want to calculate them, as the values will be model dependent?